# structure for dependent picklists

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I have 3 dependent picklists so  that Category picklist values depend on  Group values and SubCategory values depend on Category. What is a  good way to define  the  structure in Javascript that  would  describe  these dependencies? and why? I have  three variants.

```
//1
var myStruct =   {
            "Group1" : {
                "category1": ["subcategory1","subcategory2"],
                "category2": ["subcategory1","subcategory2"],
                "category3" :["subcategory1","subcategory2"]
                },
    "Group2" :{
                "category1": ["subcategory1","subcategory2"],
                "category2": ["subcategory1","subcategory2"],
                "category3" :["subcategory1","subcategory2"]
               }            
            };

//2
var myStruct2 =   {
    "Group1" : {
                "category1": {
                    "subcategory1":null,
                    "subcategory2":null
                },
                 "category2": {
                     "subcategory3":null,
                    "subcategory4":null
                },
                "category3": {
                     "subcategory5":null,
                    "subcategory6":null
                }
    },
           "Group2" :
                {
                "category3": {
                    "subcategory7":null,
                    "subcategory8":null
                },
                "category4": {
                     "subcategory9":null,
                    "subcategory10":null
                },
                "category5": {
                     "subcategory11":null,
                    "subcategory12":null
                }             
            }
        }


//3  - two separate objects describing  each  dependency

var dependency1 = {
  "Group1" :["category1","category2","category3"],
  "Group2" :["category4","category5","category6"]
  }

 var dependency2 = {
  "category1": ["subcategory1","subcategory2"],
  "category1": ["subcategory3","subcategory4"],
  "category1": ["subcategory5","subcategory6"],
  "category1": ["subcategory7","subcategory8"],
  "category1": ["subcategory9","subcategory10"],
  "category1": ["subcategory11","subcategory12"]

 }
```

or any alternative description  for this task?

Comment: So what is the question? If you are asking which of three object styles you posted above is the best, then my answer would be it depends on your requirements.

Comment: Well, I need to create a function that on the basis of one of the structures  will  create 3 picklists. Once you select option  from Group  piklist, Category picklist  displays only  those categories that  belong to selected  Group, after you select category – Subcategory  picklist displays only  options that belong to selected Category. so i'm  asking  what would  be the best structure  for this task